# nginx wordpress clean urls work in only some sub-sites

Tags: wordpress, nginx, clean-urls

I currently use this setup (with a different root path) for another site on my nginx machine, for that site, this works correctly with clean urls.

```
location ^~ /learn {
        root    /var/www/blogs/mysite/learn;
        index   index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

but, when applied to a different site on the same machine, the clean urls cause a page not found error. why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the `try_files` line, i added `/learn` before `index.php` and that fixed the problem.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /learn/index.php;
```